# Is it possible to prevent class options from being passed to some packages?

Tags: documentclass-writing, class-options

I have an option named `indent` in my document class. However, some of the packages loaded also have this option, and since the option is written in `\documentclass[...]{myclass}` as a global option, it is passed to all these packages. Is it possible to prevent this option from being passed to those packages?

The beginning of my class file looks like:

```
\def\minimclass@baseclass{article}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{
    family = @minimclass,
    prefix = @minimclass@,
}
\DeclareBoolOption[false]{indent}
\DeclareDefaultOption{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\minimclass@baseclass}}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*\relax
\LoadClass{\minimclass@baseclass}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So before I start, I'd suggest that perhaps you should rename your option for your document class. Granted that the whole concept of global options was one that was perhaps not well-conceived, it could be confusing for users of your class to have behavior that deviates from the norm.

That said, solving the problem is instructive in its own right and worth considering.

When you pass options to `\documentclass`, they're stored in the macro `\@classoptionslist` for processing. So what we want to do is get rid of a given option. We'll use the `clist` functionality of `expl3` to get what we want (so assume that you're using a current LaTeX format or have loaded the `expl3` package and are either using `\ExplSyntaxOn`…`\ExplSyntaxOff` or `\ProvidesExplClass` in your class to indicate the whole thing is using `expl3` syntax.

Now an `expl3` comma list is just a macro defined with comma-separated values so even though it doesn't follow `expl3` naming conventions, we can use `\@classoptionslist` anywhere that we would want a `clist`.

We want to remove the string `indent` if it appears in the options list, so we'll create a new comma list ❶, fill it with everything from `\@commandoptionslist` that isn't `indent` ❷ and then copy the new comma list value over to `\@commandoptionslist` ❸. Here's the code to do that:

```
\clist_new:N \l_minim_temp_clist % ❶
\clist_map_inline:Nn \@classoptionslist
{
  \str_if_eq:nnF { #1 }{ indent }
    { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_minim_temp_clist { #1 } } % ❷
}

\cs_set_eq:NN \@classoptionslist \l_minim_temp_clist % ❸
```

One note is that the `\clist_map_*` functions are not what most functional languages call a map in that they don't return a new `clist`. Rather they're more of a foreach on the elements in the `clist`.¹

All of this is possible without `expl3`, but it ends up being a lot messier (e.g., you'd need to use temporary macros and an `\ifx` to compare the two string values and the old-style looping over comma-separated lists is something that is best forgotten).

---

1. My expectation would be that the map line would have looked more like

   ```
   \clist_map_inline:NNn \SOURCE_CLIST \TARGET_CLIST { MAP CODE }
   ```

   so it's good to temper expectations from other programming languages when dealing with LaTeX code.